# Getting JSON data from external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cordova

I'm trying to get JSON data from a website using the following code, but I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html:1
If I save the data from the website as a .json file I can access it fine, but not if I access it from the website. How do I make this work from the website?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
            $.get('http://example.ca/log_sheets.json', function(data) {
                alert('get performed');
                var obj = eval ("(" + data + ")");
                $("p").html(obj[0].log_sheet.activity_type);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Display</p>
    <button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample of JSON data:

```
[{"log_sheet":{"activity_type":"Normal","activity_value":null,"carbs_value":25.0, ect... }}]
```

Code to run html page with phonegap:

```
package com.example.projectName;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Perhaps try `console.log(data)` and see what the data obj looks like

Comment: The website you're querying needs to support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), or needs to return a `script` element that you can embed into the page.

Comment: This might be a cross-domain policy issue. Also, eval is evil.

Comment: @David Johnson arbitrary comments about eval being evil need to stop.  What in this code could POSSIBLY cause a security concern?!?!

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito `console.log(data)` produces [object Object]

Comment: @DavidJohnson What do you mean by cross-domain policy issue? Also I was told in a previous related post that I could remove the eval line and have something similar to `$("p").html(data[0].log_sheet.activity_type);` and still have it work, but it didn't.

Comment: Note that if jQuery thinks you're retrieving JSON (via server mime type, a final argument of `$.get(...,'json')`, or by using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)), the data passed to the callback will already be a JS object.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It's not so much a security issue as it is a limitation. jQuery doesn't let you grab json from another domain. You have to use jsonp for that instead. "JSONP is a technique of passing data between servers using JSON. It's not an alternative to JSON."

Comment: Using `$.getJSON` and removing the eval line makes this work. Thank you @DavidJohnson and @coyotebush

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I guess eval was evil :)

Comment: Didn't expect that was the full solution, but seeing as it got you most of the way I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jQuery thinks you're retrieving JSON (via server-provided mime-type, a final argument of `$.get(...,'json')`, or by using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)), the data passed to the callback will already be a JavaScript object.

In that case, you won't want to `eval` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html
```

The link looks like a local file, therefore even though you map this in your webserver as something that should be preprocessed, it would come out as is.

If it's really a part of your project, looks like you have to post related code.

Comment: I'm running this through using phonegap and an AVD so I'll post what runs the html file.